# TableView cells are repeated/duplicated

Tags: ios, swift, cocoa-touch

So currently I'm working on a Swift project for university. It has a TableView which should have 10 cells, as my data array has 10 indices. I'm able to setup the app, everything works fine besides the fact that after 10 entries, the whole data set is repeated, starting from the 1st until last entry...[This is what the problem looks like.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WYd2q.png). (TableData is the array which holds the data for the cells)

```
override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return tableData.count
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return tableData.count
}


override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "locationCell", for: indexPath)

    let mapLocation = tableData[indexPath.row]
    cell.textLabel?.text = mapLocation.name
    return cell
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

    selectedLocation = tableData[indexPath.row]
    performSegue(withIdentifier: "fromTableToMap", sender: selectedLocation)
}
```

Comment: You probably want to return `1`  as the number of sections.

Answer (score 0):

You have

```
override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return tableData.count
}
```

Replace it with

```
override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return 1
}
```

Otherwise you are repeating your 10 rows 10 times (to make 10 sections), resulting in 100 rows.

Answer (score 0):

Use this.

```
override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return 1
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the basic concepts of `UITableView`. A TableView consists of one or more than sections, Each section consists of one or more than one cells.

```
override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return tableData.count
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return tableData.count
}
```

this means you are using 10 as sections, each having 10 rows. So it returns 10 * 10 = 100 cells (you may count manually)

it should be

```
override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return 1
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return tableData.count
}
```

now you are using 1 as sections, each having 10 rows. So it returns 1 * 10 = 10 cells (you may count manually)

Answer (score 0):

Just remove numberOfSections method from your code, by default it will take one section for tableView.